# ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Click

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sdk, galaxy-nexus

I try to develop an app with Ubuntu SDK. For that I use a Samsung Galaxy Nexus phone running with Ubuntu Touch 13.10 Saucy.

I created a project in Ubuntu SDK (App with Tabbed UI). My Device Kit is: 
UbuntuSDK for armhf (GCC ubuntu-sdk-13.10-saucy). There is no newer version of Ubuntu Touch for the Galaxy Nexus phone. Trusty or Utopic is not supported anymore.

Allmost independently what Ubuntu Project I try, the error is this:

```
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Click
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/qtc_device_applaunch.py", line 25, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Click
ImportError: cannot import name Click
```

Is this a problem with the version of my phone?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your ubuntu-touch image with the one available in the devel channel.

But the error that you get is caused by a missing dependency, try to manually re-install the debian click package on your host, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall click python3-click
```